# Java system.getProperty("user.dir") gives wrong result in ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu

I develop a Java application which is able to run cross-platform with condition in JRE version at least 1.6.0.14. Everything is work fine on a Windows machine (JRE1.6.0.14) but unwanted result in Ubuntu 8.04 with JRE1.6.0.14.

I found the errors here:

```
Document doc = docBuilder.parse (new File("webservices.xml"));
```

On the Windows machine, everything works ok, the docBuilder will refer the file at which my application located at.
Example: if my application located at C:\myApp\start.jar , it will refer webservives.xml at C:\myApp\webservices.xml (this mean it will always refer correct directory no matter where i move my application folder)

But in Ubuntu 8.04 it doesnt work.

I am able to figure out the problem by using this in application:

```
String curDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
System.out.println(curDir);
```

No matter where I place my application folder, the `curDir` always return "/home/user". `Document doc = docBuilder.parse (new File("webservices.xml"))` doesn't work until I place the webservices.xml in directory /home/user/webservices.xml.

Running my application using Netbean 6.5.1 in Ubuntu return correct curDir but running my application standalone return wrong curDir (i am using JDK1.6.0.14 and JRE1.6.0.14 same as window machine)

Why `Document doc = docBuilder.parse (new File("webservices.xml"))` cant work properly in ubuntu JRE1.6.0.14?

Any idea to make my application work standalone in Ubuntu 8.04 just like in window machine?

Comment: Why isn't webservices.xml inside the jar file in the first place? Do you need to change it?

Answer (score 9):

Do not rely on the current directory to read files that come with the application. Instead, use [ClassLoader.getResource()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) (to access file relative to the classpath) or [Class.getResouce()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) to access files inside packages.

**Edit:** The above is only good for readonly access. Files that will be modified should be stored in the user's home directory (System property `user.home`), not the application directory, because the latter causes many problems:

- multiple users running the application at the same time might overwrite each other's changes
- Users cannot backup or migrate their data easily
- It is incompatible with a properly secure system of user privileges, where normal users do not have write access to application directories to prevent viruses from infecting applications.

For small amounts of data, you can use the [Java preferences API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/prefs/package-frame.html).

**Edit2**:
For that particular requirement, this should work (needs the file to be in the classpath):

```
Document doc = docBuilder.parse (
    new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("webservices.xml").toURI()););
```

Comment: I am confused using the ClassLoader.getResource(). i need to modify the contents of webservices.xml which store server ip from time to time, am i able to modify it inside packages?

Comment: My application folder concept is similar to portable browser folder, you can execute my application as long as you copy the entire application folder. Which mean no matter where you place the folder (even in portable drive), the program still can access the file webservices.xml, that's why i need access the file which same directory with the application. Everything work fine in window machine but not ubuntu 8.04...

Answer (score 8):

`System.getProperty("user.dir")` returns the current directory the user is executing the program, rather than where the program is located.

Comment: I dint use System.getProperty("user.dir") in my application. I add that line just to debug my application due to these line cant work in ubuntu: Document doc = docBuilder.parse (new File("webservices.xml"));

Comment: @winston: that doesn't matter. If you provide a relative file name (such as "webservices.xml") then it will be searched in the current directory which is returned by that system property.

Answer (score 2):

user.dir is the current working directory of your shell so you cd to it first [Sun Java tutorial definition of user.dir](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)

Answer (score -3):

Try

`Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new File("./webservices.xml"));`